# Flow {| syntax for defining types

Tags: javascript, flowtype

In defining types, I found two different syntax. The first one being;

```
type Type = {
    ...
}
```

The second one being:

```
type Type = {|
    ...
|}
```

I tried to check in the documentation but I didn't find anything that describes the second syntax. What is the difference between these two definitions?

Comment: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't manage to find it

Comment: Duplicate of [What does flow {| brace pipe |} syntax do?](/q/48393027/4642212). Also relevant: [What does {| ... |} mean in javascript?](/q/48664987/4642212).